# What is correct way to play pcm with web audio api

Tags: javascript, html, audio, pcm

I want to play raw pcm through web audio api

In example below pcm.raw is 32bit float PCM 8000hz

What am I doing wrong?

```
function play() {
      let pcm_data = fs.readFileSync('pcm.raw');

      let rawbuffer = new Float32Array(pcm_data)
      let audioBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(1, rawbuffer.length, 8000)
      audioBuffer.copyToChannel( rawbuffer, 0);

      const source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = audioBuffer;
      source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
      source.start();
};
```